# ffmpeg overlay timing issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a `png` as overlay to a `mov` video with ffmpeg (version 4.2.2) using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i ./input.mov -i ./overlay.png -y -filter_complex "overlay=enable='between(t,1,4)'" ./output.mp4`

Now my understanding of `overlay=enable='between(t,1,4)` is that the overlay will be added at one second and will be removed at 4 seconds since the begin of the video but the output is somehow different.

The overlay is added at roughly 2:66 and it is removed at 5:14.

Trying with different values result in even more confusing outputs.

eg:

- `between(t,3,10)` --> 3:12 | 11:05
- `between(t,2,7)` --> 2:65 | 7:22
- `between(t,1,2)` --> the overlay is not added ad all

The metadata of the input video are the following

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2020-04-19T08:09:00.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:14.84, start: 0.053333, bitrate: 849 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/unknown), 828x1792 [SAR 1:1 DAR 207:448], 848 kb/s, 23.34 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-19T08:09:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
```

I also tried to convert the video to mp4 (with `ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4`) before applying the overlay but the issue is still there.

Edit: I downloaded a test mp4 video and the command is working as expected so it is definitely something wrong with my input video. Any idea what it is?

Edit 2: Here's the output of ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './input.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2020-04-22T07:49:31.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:17.80, start: 0.051667, bitrate: 1097 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/unknown/unknown), 750x1334 [SAR 1:1 DAR 375:667], 1097 kb/s, 12.96 fps, 60 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-22T07:49:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
Input #1, png_pipe, from './overlay.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 83x128, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to './output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 750x1334 [SAR 1:1 DAR 375:667], q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  326 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.35 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  499 fps=461 q=31.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:07.23 bitrate= 290.0kbits/frame=  830 fps=494 q=31.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:12.75 bitrate= 329.0kbits/frame=  956 fps=491 q=-1.0 Lsize=     593kB time=00:00:15.88 bitrate= 306.0kbits/s dup=726 drop=0 speed=8.16x
video:581kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.030694%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] frame I:6     Avg QP:18.73  size: 30783
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] frame P:288   Avg QP:21.57  size:  1150
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] frame B:662   Avg QP:30.94  size:   119
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] consecutive B-frames:  4.9%  6.9%  4.1% 84.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] mb I  I16..4: 19.1% 64.5% 16.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  0.9%  0.5%  P16..4:  2.4%  0.4%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:94.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.0%  L0:43.8% L1:55.9% BI: 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] 8x8 transform intra:53.9% inter:64.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 18.2% 20.8% 13.9% inter: 0.1% 0.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 63%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 48% 17% 29%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 32% 15%  3%  4%  4%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 21%  7%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] ref P L0: 74.6%  4.0% 13.4%  8.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] ref B L0: 80.0% 17.6%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] ref B L1: 97.6%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcad0001200] kb/s:298.58
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: @llogan I've edited the post adding the output of the command.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a link to `input.mov` or any other similar video that has the same issue?

Comment: I don't have the original video but I reproduced similar issues with the file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yaKe-jmjX0YnbrERqgMGbIOS4vqsOYO2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Converting the video without copying the video and audio codec (`ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4`) results in an output where the overlays are applied correctly using the command wrote above.

I think the issue is related to the start time of the video. 
Not sure if there's a cleaner solution that doesn't involve converting the video.